# Error referencing self in a dict variable (python)

Tags: python, self

I'm a bit new to Python and can't figure this one out. I'm not able to debug a similar error in some code I'm writing. I replicated it below.

Why is it when I reference `self.method()` in a dict in a global variable, I get a name error? Error below:

```
$ python -tt error_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "error_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    class Test(object):
  File "error_test.py", line 4, in Test
    'key_one': self.method_one(),
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

```
class Test(object):

    some_dictionary = {
        'key_one': self.method_one(),
        'key_two': self.method_two(),
        'key_three': self.method_three()
    }

    def __init__(self): 
        pass

    def method_one(self):
        pass

    def method_two(self):
        pass

    def method_three(self):
        pass
```

Comment: How would it know what `self` refers to at that point? On top of that, you have a class variable that's expected to refer to instance variables. Which instance should it refer to? You may want to rethink your data structure.

Comment: `self` has no meaning outside a member function. you try to access `self` in the static part of your class. there no `self` is defined... and: what are you trying to achieve? how do you intend to use `some_dictionary`?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you want to do this:

```
class Test(object):

    def __init__(self): 
        self.some_dictionary = {
            'key_one': self.method_one(),
            'key_two': self.method_two(),
            'key_three': self.method_three()
        }

    def method_one(self):
        pass

    def method_two(self):
        pass

    def method_three(self):
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to define a method before you call it. You need to do this:

```
class Test(object):    
    def __init__(self): 
        pass

    def method_one(self):
        pass

    def method_two(self):
        pass

    def method_three(self):
        pass



    some_dictionary = {
        'key_one': method_one,
        'key_two': method_two,
        'key_three': method_three
    }
```

Also, there is no `self` at the class level, only at the function level. If you need to use self, you need to move the dictionary definition into __init__ or another class method.

If you want `some_dictionary` to be part of `Test` you need to define it in `__init__` like this:

```
class Test(object):

    def method_one(self):
        print('Method 1')

    def method_two(self, x, y):
        print(x + y)

    def method_three(self, x):
        print(x * x)

    def __init__(self): 
        self.some_dictionary = {
        'key_one': self.method_one,
        'key_two': self.method_two,
        'key_three': self.method_three
    }

test = Test()
test.some_dictionary['key_one']()
test.some_dictionary['key_two'](1, 2)
test.some_dictionary['key_three'](6)
```

Alternatively, if you want `key_one, key_two, key_three` to be the results of those function calls, this will work:

```
class Test(object):

    def method_one(self):
        return 'Method 1'

    def method_two(self, x, y):
        return x + y

    def method_three(self, x):
        return x * x

    def __init__(self): 
        self.some_dictionary = {
        'key_one': self.method_one(),
        'key_two': self.method_two(1, 2),
        'key_three': self.method_three(6)
    }

test = Test()
print(test.some_dictionary)
```

Comment: I think he wants the values returned by the methods. So probably the methods need to be class/static methods.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini Possibly, but as the question currently stands, it's unclear.

Comment: So methods in dicts cannot contain parameters? I cannot seem to use self inside a dict. If I attempt to say:  

def method_one(self, x, y):
pass   

    And then call it with method_one(x, y) it will give an argument error (expected 3, 2 given). If I attempt to use self.method_one(x, y) I get "self is not defined". Additionally you cannot call method_one(self, x, y). It doesn't make any sense. It works fine if I put them in a subclass and call the subclass. But I cannot call the method directly from within a dict???

Comment: @user1601871 I think the edit I just added should answer your question.